# How to use Spring Security ACL when my domain identifiers are of String type?

Tags: java, spring-security-acl

I faced with strange and unexpected situation with Spring Security ACL when tried to create ACL using `MutableAclService.createAcl(ObjectIdentity objectIdentity)`.

The matter is that `ObjectIdentity` uses `Serializable` type for identifiers.
At the same time my domains use `String` type for this purpose. Ids are generated in such way:

```
String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

And then I try to add ACL using the following structure:

```
ObjectIdentity identity = new ObjectIdentityImpl(clazz, id);
aclService.createAcl(identity);
```

After that I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ad169805-a2d1-4324-ba11-c98cc679e594"

I found that Spring Security ACL uses `Long` type for identifiers.

So, the questions are:

1. What are the best practices in such cases (do I need to use, for example, hashcode of my object as an identifier, or smth else)?
2. Why `Serializable` is mentioned everywhere, but in fact it must be long?

P.S. And the SQL data types for identifiers are also numbers - bigserial.

Comment: 1. hascode is not a good ideea, you can have two identity with same hashCode.
why you dont use SQL identifier for ObjectIdentity ? It is a garant  you have a guarantee that it is unique
2. Posible becouse you use an JdbcAclService implimentation for aclService, you can create your own for custom behavior or extend existing.
I recommand to use database identifier.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @lilalinux, as Vasile Bors suggested for the 2nd point is using your own acl implementation.
As for the 1st point - whatever you want to use as id. For instance, you can use uuid v4 as String.

Answer (score 4):

It's been over three years but i will leave this for anyone still struggling with this one:

As of 2017-2018 (especially with from this commit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/6decf1c8ef8e31b0d9de9a2f2b364ce682d8b166#diff-bdb889847e56650fc7c52f9de584ba22 and on) Spring security ACL started implementing classes to solve this problem.

I am currently using Spring Security ACL 5.2.2.RELEASE which narrows down the solution of this problem to 2 simple configurations modifications:

```
  @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
        BasicLookupStrategy basicLookupStrategy = new BasicLookupStrategy(
                dataSource,
                aclCache(),
                aclAuthorizationStrategy(),
                new ConsoleAuditLogger()
        );
        basicLookupStrategy.setAclClassIdSupported(true); // <--- this line
        return basicLookupStrategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
        JdbcMutableAclService jdbcMutableAclService = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource,lookupStrategy(),aclCache());
        jdbcMutableAclService.setAclClassIdSupported(true); //<-- And this line.
        return jdbcMutableAclService;
    }
```

When using the above configuration the spring acl assumes you have an extra field in your table "acl_class" called "class_id_type" which holds the information of what type is your entity's ID. For example my PostgreSQL definition for this table is as follows:

```
create table if not exists acl_class(
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    class varchar(100) not null,
    class_id_type varchar(100),
    constraint unique_uk_2 unique(class)
);
```